# How to show alternative CJK glyphs in WIndows CE?

Tags: unicode, windows-ce, cjk, truetype, glyph-substitution

We are using the "Arial Unicode MS" font to display Chinese (CJK glyphs) text. Unfortunately one of the shown glyphs (U+76f4) is not recognized by our Chinese customers, since the default "style" in the font is Japanese. There is support in the font file for glyph substitution, using the GSUB table.
Is there any way to make use of this substitution in .NET 2.0 CF on Windows CE 6.0?

I have tried to change the locale without any luck.

Comment: This font is rather ugly for Chinese, you'd better use a proffesional chinese font.

Answer (score 0):

Using OpenType-info.tex to find all the features of Arial Unicode MS. The following code selected  simplified Chinese shape.

```
\font\cnshape="Arial Unicode MS:script=hani:language=ZHS:+locl"%or JAN/KOR/ZHS/ZHT
{\cnshape 直}
```